# puzzled by "no space" complaint from apt

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, kernel, disk-usage

Background:  My / partition was at 93%, but I had some unallocated space so I created a new home for /usr .   After the move the space usage looks like:

```
>df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
//dev/sda1       15747484  6822736   8124800  46% /
udev             1954244        4   1954240   1% /dev
tmpfs             786052     1040    785012   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1965124      512   1964612   1% /run/shm
cgroup           1965124        0   1965124   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       62993332 30014168  29779216  51% /home
/dev/sda7       26540640       32  26540608   1% /windows
/dev/sda8       10320184  7156516   2639432  74% /usr
```

Now the system runs but when I allowed a normal software update, the kernel headers portion produced an error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-55_3.2.0-55.85_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-55/arch/arm/mach-pxa/include/mach/eseries-irq.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-55/arch/arm/mach-pxa/include/mach/eseries-irq.h'): No space left on device
```

This "space" complaint and the df output above seem to contradict one another.

I get the same error when I try fixing the repository (sudo apt-get -f install).  Thinking I had too many old kernel versions I tried removing some (sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.2.0-38              linux-headers-3.2.0-38-generic      linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic ... ) but this produces an error and a suggestion that I try apt-get -f install .

Some system information:

```
> uname -a
Linux <hostname> 3.2.0-55-generic-pae #85-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 14:03:15 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
> cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS"
```

I'm afraid I won't be able to update any software until I get this headers issue resolved.  I hope someone out there can help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `/boot`?

Comment: Could you include the output of the command `df -i`? You may not be out of raw data capacity, but out of inodes.

Comment: Thanks gertvdijk .  Indeed df -i yields ...


    /dev/sda8       655360 648327    7033   99% /usr

I'll try remaking the filesystem and report back...

Comment: I have same problem and more the enough space ?? apt-get -f install fails

Comment: Please **edit** your answer to include the new important details! That is how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

The inodes have it.  Thanks again, gertvdijk.

In my comment you can see that the filesystem, though not nearly full, was about out of inodes.  After looking at man mkfs.ext4 I decided to cut its bytes/inodes ratio in half.  This ratio is set by the -i option.  A quick calculation based on the outputs of df -k and df -i showed mine to be about 2^14, so I would go with 2^13.  (Below I've used {} to indicate placeholder objects whose details might be distracting.)  I then

1. decided to use temporary storage {tempmountpoint} mounted on {tempdev}.  This is big enough to hold the contents of my /usr tree.
2. copied the contents of /usr into {tempmountpoint} with

   ```
   rsync -avu /usr/ {tempmountpoint}
   ```
3. unmounted both of these
4. mounted /usr to {tempdev} (so I could keep working on other things through all of this)
5. reformatted /usr's original (and eventual target) partition with

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 -i 8192  /dev/sda8
   ```
6. mounted /dev/sda8 to {tempmountpoint}.
7. copied the contents of the temporary /usr back into its target partition with

   ```
   rsync -avu /usr/ {tempmountpoint} .
   ```
8. Finally, I looked up the (new) UUID with

   ```
   ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
   ```
9. used this UUID to edit the /usr entry in /etc/fstab, and
10. rebooted.

Updates are working normally now.  And the filesystem looks to be in reasonable shape, as in:

```
> df -k /usr
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8       10156344 7349228   2282880  77% /usr
> df -i /usr
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda8      1310720 679355 631365   52% /usr
```

Some notes:

(i) /home already had its own partition.  If it had been in /usr I would approach this a little differently.

(ii) Choice of tools:  I like ls /dev/disk/by-uuid because ls is very, very well known.  I used rsync partly because when I had to do something else for a while before getting back to this, I could run the same rsync command again to "refresh" the copy.  Also, I like it and it can do this.  Others may have different utilities that satisfy these criteria.  For example, until a few years ago I would've used cpio.  Whatever gets you through the byte.

(iii) The placeholders refer to what had been the fat32 (vfat) filesystem on /dev/sda7, mounted at /windows.  I reformatted it in cold blood before the above procedure.  I never bothered changing the mountpoint name, which could be confusing second-hand.

Thanks to all who helped or contributed.

Answer (score 0):

It says that you have no space left on /usr partition, you can try to remove something there.

Did you tried apt-get -f install?